# When pitest cannot find the test classes

Tags: java, maven, testing, pitest

It seems that this is a quite common issue and I personally stumbled on it at least a couple of times.

Some of the main causes being:

- Forgetting to run the test (and thus create the test classes) before running pitest: [Pitest can't detect class of test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475934/pitest-cant-detect-class-of-test), [PITest cannot find tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151078/pitest-cannot-find-tests).
- Miss-configured `targetTests`: [pitest doesn't find tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179035/pitest-doesnt-find-tests)
- Improper use of the `assert` keyword: [pitest not able to locate junit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948524/pitest-not-able-to-locate-junit-test)

However, today I stumbled upon a new case of 0 tests found, which I struggle to solve. Let us consider this project: https://github.com/bonnyfone/vectalign.
It is a small project and includes one only test class:

```
src
 |
 +- main
 |   |
 |   ...
 |
 +- test
     |
     +- java
          |
          +- VectAlignTest.java
```

I added pitest to the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</plugin>
```

I run the command `mvn clean test org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`.
While the test run just fine, for some reason pitest cannot locate them:

```
12:23:16 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 12:23:16 PM PIT >> INFO : Found  0 tests
...
================================================================================
- Statistics
================================================================================
>> Generated 910 mutations Killed 0 (0%)
>> Ran 0 tests (0 tests per mutation)
```

You can find the complete `pom.xml` here: https://pastebin.com/F28ZpcMk
And here is the complete output for `mvn clean test org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`: https://pastebin.com/tWHgq43a

Now my question is, what is going wrong in this particular case? How does pitest determine which are the test classes?

Your help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

PITest did not find my classes or test classes because I did not have them in a package.  Once I put them in a package, everything worked great.  I suspect that you could also specify the class and test class locations manually.

To quote that answer at the (now deleted) linked question:

> I just spent a great deal of time with the same message
>
> > No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters.
>
> My problem was simple:  I had created a couple of test projects in
> IntelliJ using Maven.  But I did not have a package.  I was using the
> default package and PITest was failing every time.  The PITest has a
> plugin that might work with just the default package if you specify
> the class and test classes.  But all the documentation said that it
> should work by default.  A verbose output even showed that PITest was
> finding the correct project folders, but it still didn't work.  Henry
> Cole was even good enough (the developer of PITest) to look at my
> POM.xml file and confirm that it looked good.
>
> In summary, PITest works great if you put your Java code in a package.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing quite the same issue. For me specifying the exact test packages helped. In your case maybe you could add:

```
<configuration>
    <targetTests>
      <param>VectAlignTest*</param>
    </targetTests>
</configuration>
```

But of course, this is quite a dirty workaround. Maybe somebody knows the root cause of the problem.